# Writing to two textboxes simultaneously

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF app I have two textboxes, and I am looking for the following:

I want that if the user writes something on `textbox1`  the app would put the same value into `textbox2`,

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textbox2"/>
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: If `textbox2` allows input, then you are going to have to be a lot more specific about your rules. For example, what should happen if textbox2 already contains some user input text?

Comment: I just wanted to make my question more simple, what I really need is that if the user input some content to textbox1 then textbox2 would be fill in with same content, and to do the same if the user input some stuff to textbox2 it would fill in textbox1 (override old data)

Comment: @IOException see if my answer helps you. It's tested and it works for the simple case you demonstrated - if it doesn't work in your real use case, feel free to give some more information and I will help you achieve what you want to.

Comment: @IOException: Don't make the question simple. If you don't include your **real** requirements, then you won't get the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will work:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1" />
<TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Text="{Binding ElementName=textbox1, Path=Text}"/>
```

Now what this does is that the [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `textbox2` is *bound* to the `Text` property of `textbox1`. Every change you do in `textbox1` will automatically be reflected in `textbox2`.

---

## EDIT: Real Requirements

Based on your comment, here's a solution which might be what you want to do:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Text="{Binding TheText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Text="{Binding TheText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

and add this C# class:

```
public class MySimpleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string theString = String.Empty;

    public string TheString
    {
        get => this.theString;
        set
        {
            if(this.theString != value)
            {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
                this.theString = value;
            }
        }
    }
        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

What I did not show is how to wire up the `MySimpleViewModel` with the actual view. However, if you have problems with that, I can certainly show that as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works only after I'm clicking inside textbox2, is it possible to make it update without putting the mouse inside the textbox?

Comment: @IOException give me a sec, I'm working on an updated version which takes into account your real requirements.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow can you tell me what [CanBeNull] do

Comment: @tabby it's a [ReSharper annotation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html) which helps with static analysis. It's not required for the code to compile or anything, it's just leftover from my IDE I forgot to remove before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative for you

**This will also do samething**

Simple way: **C#**

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```