# Conditioned binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some `TextBox`es which are all bound to a string property `TheText` in the ViewModel

```
<TextBox x:Name="t1" Text="{Binding TheText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox x:Name="t2" Text="{Binding TheText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox x:Name="t3" Text="{Binding TheText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

the ViewModel:

```
string theString = String.Empty;

public string TheText
{
    get { return this.theString; }
    set
    {
        if (this.theString != value)
        {
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            this.theString = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
if(something)
   then bind only t1 and t2 and cancel binding of t3
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You could use converters maybe?

Comment: Why not just set t3 to a default value or invalid status. Bind/Clear will degrade your performance.

Comment: why do you need it?

Comment: why the downvotes? it will block my accouct

Comment: @IOException see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228362/375646) which also applies to your question getting downvotes. But let me reassure you, getting downvotes does not mean you are getting blocked.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow so you're justify the downvotes?

Comment: I'm not justifying them, it's just that the link describes some common reasons for downvotes, which seemingly applied to your question as well. Apart from that, as you may have seen, I edited your question 2 hours ago because *I wanted to help you* by improving it so that it won't get any more downvotes but rather constructive answers.

Comment: @IOException just a small note: you should not be asking for upvotes as [it is looked down upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63440/375646), because respect (and reputation in this case) is earned, not asked for. Other than that, since you cannot yet [see vote counts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), let me tell you that your question currently has 2 upvotes and 3 downvotes totaling -1 votes. Anyways, don't think about the downvotes too much. Everyone gets them sometimes; I have questions and answers that have been voted down and so has *anyone else* here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just create 3 properties and bind them if needed ?

you will have TheText1, TheText2 and TheText3 with 3 initializations but that's not bad. You just have to set your "TheTextX" as needed.

If you really need to "delete" the binding just do the following:

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(yourTextBoxToDeleteBind, TextBox.TextProperty)
```

Comment: I am binding all in one because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50584777/9859342)

Comment: @IOException  this seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) so you need to explain your actual problem. [I already told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584777/writing-to-two-textboxes-simultaneously#comment88179036_50584777) on the linked question that I am willing to help you achieve your actual goals, and I bet there won't be any need for clearing bindings or anything ;)

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Like I said, creating a VM property for each textbox would solve his problem and it wouldn't be neccesary to clear the binding. I have already posted him "2" solutions. If you think there is another one pls post it because I couldn't come up with any more :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez I saw your solutions and I liked them, so I upvoted :) My post was not a criticism to your answer or anything, it's just that I feel like OP is having the so-called [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/375646) and therefore complicating things more than necessary. There would certainly be easier solutions, maybe even easier than 3 dedicated bindings. But we would need some more information about the actual problem. Further, I already posted [a solution on their other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50584806/7571171) which seemingly lead to this problem...

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow I didn't mean to criticize your comment just the opposite, if I missed another solution I would like to know it, sorry if it sounded like I was complaining :D.

Comment: JuanCarlosRodriguez no problem :D seems like we both misunderstood each other... but no, I have no other solutions either. Yours are good and should help the OP. If they don't, @IOException needs to give some more information.